# Joining a startup. What should I know?

Tags: startup

I got an offer from a start-up (in Silicon Valley) which I believe has a really bright future. The team I am going to work with are very talented, and most importantly friendly. I believe I am going to learn a lot from them.

This was my first offer and because I have not seen other offers from other companies, I do not know what should I expect. And what is the norm out there. I gradaute in 3 months and will get my PhD.

What should I expect from the offer from a startup.

Thanks.

Comment: We cannot really tell whether you should take the offer or not. This is your decision.
Question with specific choices are off-topic.

Comment: @Helena Thanks for your comment. I just want to know about the general terms for job offers. I have not seen offers from other companies to compare. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase your question more specifically about typical pay situation in startups and remove some of your extra questions. ("Should you never accept your first offer", or "Should I accept?").

Comment: @Helena Sure. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 5):

> Joining a startup. What should I know?

By far the most important thing to know about startups is most of them fail. Mostly because they're funding mines or selling pipe dreams. Find out about the people who run it is always the best bet. If it's their 7th startup, or they had a fancy job and then suddenly left etc,.

Answer (score 1):

> By far the most important thing to know about startups is most of them
> fail.

This is another great answer by Kilisi, but I think it's a bit short on practical advice.

Most startups *do* fail (I think the figure is 9 in 10 - too lazy to look for source for this) and working for the one which doesn't will make you very employable and hopefully moderately wealthy/insanely rich. Deal with those circumstance when they happen, but the chances are it won't and you should plan for this.

Working for a startup...

1. Will consume your life. You need to make a real effort to regularly
   touch base with family and friends.
2. Probably won't offer much in the way of a pension or (m)any other
   benefits. That's probably ok for a few years at at the younger end of
   life*.
3. Probably won't offer you a great salary - instead you're working on
   cool stuff, and are given stock/options

Because of the high chance of failure, you need to plan for when they go bust or just stop paying. Keep outgoings to a minimum. They'll probably expect you to keep working anyway, because all those riches are only 2 months away - You'll be at the sharp end; the code. Is it really 2 months to finish? Don't forget you may not have any customers yet.

Remember, your primary duty is to yourself and your family and that's where your loyalty lies, not your employer.

- Not true at all. The first decade or 2 of pension planning/contributions are the most important. But you won't appreciate that until you're in your 50's.

Comment: *"The first decade or 2 of pension planning/contributions are the most important."* - is that still true nowadays? Most returns on capital are at rock bottom. It was true in the days when employers paid *final* salary - when obviously it was important to have accrual years - or when interest rates and tax concessions provided significant growth in a pot. Nowadays, the returns are much more marginal - it makes more sense to pay down interest-charging debt first (if you have any, like a mortgage or a car loan), than to save for a pension.

Comment: @Steve - you're probably right, now I think about it some more. Certainly paying down anything interest charging is excellent advice.

Comment: Indeed. As I say, it *was* true in the past, two to four decades ago, when workers rarely had any debt except their mortgage, and pensions provided good (and often risk-free, large-employer-backed, inflation-proofed) returns. But the opposite is now the case - pensions are barely returning the cash invested (compulsory employer contributions and tax reliefs are often the only thing that prevent immediate negative cash returns, after charges and inflation are factored), and the vast majority of workers are servicing debts whose interest charges far exceed pension returns.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the startups are ageist, unless you worm your way to management/shareholder position, you will be laid off and replaced by someone fresher before you reach late 20s. Especially if you are in sillicon valley where age discrimination is basically industry standart.

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question at all, more like expressing your own bitterness.

Comment: It does, question asks what should one know, and this adds one more fact alongside other answers.

Comment: "Fact" is not what I would call anything that you've included, at least unless you can provide some sources?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, it's true that he hasn't provided proof, but it is conventional wisdom these days that most businesses in IT are oriented towards exploiting the enthusiasm and underemployment of young workers, rather than providing steady lifelong IT careers. So unless you're the owner of the startup, it is probably something to watch out for.

Comment: @Steve It is? I've been in startups my whole life, still am, and that is not the "wisdom" I have. So is there something, anything, to back it up?

Comment: What proof do you exactly want, just google "tech age discrimination" and you will find gazillion papers, videos and articles on topic. Hell just send CV with your younger photo and see your success skyrocket. I could talk about  experiences of mine and my friends but these would be dismissed as anecdotal right ?

Comment: @TerryGlebnerr something more than an unsourced article that someone has created on a whim and has no accountability over? It's very easy to just read articles that fit your world view and take them like gospel, but that doesn't make what they say true.  And as I look at recent 5 startups I worked with, in every single one the median age would be over 30.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, if you've been in "many" startups, then that's one red flag for continuity of employment with startups - bearing in mind a young worker has to keep this gig going until at least *70 years old*. Secondly, in what capacity do you now work? I gather management (at least at a junior level), so your primary value now is organisational, not technical.

Comment: @Steve Swing and miss, I was a contractor, moving from one to another is perfectly normal - not a red flag, and it pays to see the world and experience many places first hand. But also I am not sure why is this about me, OP made some extremely strong and wide-reaching claims, so I am merely asking for SOME shred of evidence to back them up. Now if he wanted to expand the answer and say that OP may face those issues, because they are common, that's something probably stomach able.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, some may call it contracting, others may call it casualisation of employment. I agree with you though that evidence here wouldn't go amiss, and the OP may be over-egging the pudding by suggesting the cut-off is late 20s, but almost everyone is aware of the problem and has some anecdotal evidence. I knew a Cobol programmer about 8 years ago who was on the scrapheap at 44 after redundancy. He was too old to teach new tricks, but arguably not old enough to have had a solid institutional career which often keeps guys in their late 60s in paid consultancy work.

Comment: @Steve Why do you keep trying to fit my life into your narrative, especially when you know literally nothing about it? Because when you do then eventually, like in this case, you run into a risk of calling "owner/CEO of a ~10 people big IT consultancy company" as "casualization of employment".

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, if you're the *owner* of a consultancy firm of 10 people, then why are *you* trying to fit your life into the OPs narrative, where he clearly makes an exception for those who (as he puts it...) "worm [their] way to [a] management/shareholder position"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112443/discussion-between-tymoteusz-paul-and-steve).